# Should we have a banner reminding answer authors that AI-generated content is not allowed?

Tags: discussion, ai-generated-content

As announced in [this main Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera), an [experiment was run](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426353/testing-an-ai-generated-content-policy-banner-on-stack-overflow) on Stack Overflow which found that randomly selected users who were reminded that content generated by artificial intelligence is not allowed were significantly less likely to post content that was later flagged as being AI-generated.

Here is how the banner looked during the test:
[image: Image of banner reminding users AI-generated content is prohibited]

The network developers have offered to allow us to roll this type of banner out to our site. The banner would read as follows:

> **Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on Medical Sciences. [Learn more](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1392/ban-chatgpt-and-ai-generated-answers-on-medicalsciences-se)

The network developers note:

> - The banner will display once users select the answer field
> - All users will see this banner when posting an answer with the option to dismiss. Once dismissed, logged-in users will not see this banner again

So presumably there will be some sort of dismiss button on the final version of the banner.

#### Given that [AI-generated content is not allowed on Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1392/ban-chatgpt-and-ai-generated-answers-on-medicalsciences-se), should we request that this banner be activated on our site?

Answer (score 4):

##### Yes, we should request the banner

Although we have only seen a handful of apparently AI-generated answers, this banner may decrease negative contributions.

Comment: Can we add that answers need sources and link to the meta post as well, while we are at it?

Comment: Sadly, the developers made it pretty clear in other channels that only two wordings of the banner are available. And the second banner version only mentions that AI-generated posts require citations.

Comment: Yeah no worries, saw that in the meta post as well (there apparently are even difficulties having a properly translated banner for language sites)! Sorry my comment was meant rather tongue-in-cheek, should have clarified more

Answer (score 0):

#### No, the banner is noise -- we don't need it

Only a handful of apparently AI-generated answers have been posted on Medical Sciences. This banner uses valuable space and the activation would be a waste of developer effort.